# after registration submitted Internal Server Error

Tags: error, registration, magento-2.1.9, http-error-500

**Internal Server Error**
The server encountered an internal error or **misconfiguration** and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Please refer below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to access other pages? Have you made any changes in you .htaccess file?

Comment: no,but other pages access easily

Comment: Ok, please enable developer mode by running command : php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer  and add display errors to magento root index.php file : ini_set('display_errors', 1); it will give you the actual error.

Comment: Also please check webserver log at /var/log/httpd/  or may be at /var/log/apache2.. You may also get the actual error when you run  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: After run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy then var/log folder showing only 3 file--1>exception.log,2>debug.log3>system.log

Comment: Please check those log file if you can find any error within them. Are you able to check server's  /var/log/httpd/ or you can ask your server support to check the error in server error log. This log is different than the Magento var/log

Answer (score -1):

Please enable developer mode by running command :

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

and then add display errors to magento root index.php file :

> `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

It will give you the actual error.

**Update 1:**

Upon checking your log, it seems like there is some issue with max execution time. Please set following code to index.php file:

> `ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);`

or

> `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` //To set execution time to infinite

Please let me know how it goes.

**Update 2**

As per your comment it is not being affected while checking with phpinfo.php (phpinfo()). Please get the max_execution_time updated by server support team to rectify the issue.

Comment: again it's redirecting a internet server error.I didn't show any error massege.

Comment: Oh I see, please check server log in that case, the path is updated in my recent comment. You can check if you have local setup or you might have to contact server administrator if it is remote server.

Comment: main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-11-28 10:31:26] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-11-28 10:3

Comment: [2018-11-28 10:38:26] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-11-28 10:38:26] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_56f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

Comment: Those are common error and doesn't break the page. Server log would be helpful to resolve the issue. Please contact server guy :)

Comment: ok how to disable developers mode?

Comment: please run following command: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production;   Please note that if site is live than you need to set production mode, otherwise its good to work with developer mode to get the detailed error reporting on issues. Do you have any entry in exception.log?

Comment: Wed Nov 28 06:43:29.776327 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 11532] [client 46.229.168.142:29638] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\AbstractSource' not found in /home/torerocorp/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 11

Comment: [Wed Nov 28 06:44:10.506373 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 6690] [client 54.36.149.32:36218] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\AbstractSource' not found in /home/torerocorp/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 11
[Wed Nov 28 06:54:08.137705 2018] [access_compat:error] [pid 6690] [client 34.193.245.222:33932] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/torerocorp/public_html/app/etc/config.php

Comment: [Wed Nov 28 07:03:30.062463 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 9267] [client 202.142.98.102:59793] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 410 seconds, referer: http://torerocorp.com/india/customer/account/create/
[Wed Nov 28 07:03:30.062995 2018] [core:error] [pid 9267] [client 202.142.98.102:59793] End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: http://torerocorp.com/india/customer/account/create/

Comment: Please ensure if /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/AbstractSource.php is available at your setup, also set 755 permission to app/etc folder recursively by running command : chmod -R 755 app/etc

Comment: Updated my answer, please add ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800); to root index.php file.

Comment: all changes done,but still showing the error.Please help.

Comment: create phpinfo.php file with code  <?php phpinfo(); ?> and run  http://yoursite.com/phpinfo.php in browser, check what the value it is showing for max_execution_time?

Comment: max_execution_time ----400

Comment: This needs to be updated, the settings what we made ( ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800) ) is not affecting the max_execution_time, please ask server support to set it infinite or max possible value. You can see following line in your error log mentioning about this error: mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 410 seconds

Comment: Delete operation is forbidden for current area --new error show

Comment: again Internal Server Error

Comment: Nafisa, please get the max_execution_time updated, please recheck issue once it is shown with updated value in phpinfo.php file :)

Comment: Yes this is effected now--1800.But still this error showing.

Comment: Need to check with other settings then..